# ¿COMO PUEDO CONCATENAR :NEW O :OLD CON UNA VARIABLE?

Tags: oracle

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como puedo concatenar :NEW ó :OLD con una variable # Oracle #Script #Concatenar.

Con un Select recojo el nombre de la columna que estoy actualizando y lo guardo en una Variable que se llama updatedcols de manera que quiero concatenar la variable con :OLD para recoger el dato antigua de ese campo pero no me deja.

Muchas gracias

```
create or replace TRIGGER TEST_TRIGG
BEFORE UPDATE ON ALUMNES
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
updatedcols varchar2(3000);
begin
for r in (select column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name ='ALUMNES')
    loop
       IF UPDATING(r.column_name) THEN
       updatedcols := updatedcols || ',' || r.column_name;
        INSERT INTO control_de_dades_alumnes (TIPUS_OPERACIO, USUARI, DIA, COLUMNA, DADA_ANTIGA) VALUES ('UPDATE', USER, SYSDATE, updatedcols, :OLD.updatedcols);
       END IF;
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Primero decídete, es `mysql` o es `oracle` (tiene pinta que es `oracle`). Segundo, trata de dar una explicación más detallada de tu problema. La única explicación que se ve es lo que has escrito en el título, y no ayuda mucho. Te invito a repasar [ask]. Saludos